# Simplify codes in python

Tags: python-3.x

Could someone help me change this code into for loop or any simplify version? Thank you very much!

```
        if row == 0 and col == 0 and self.board[5] == ' ':
          return True
        elif row == 0 and col == 1 and self.board[6] == ' ':
          return True
        elif row == 0 and col == 2 and self.board[7] == ' ':
          return True
        elif row == 1 and col == 0 and self.board[9] == ' ':
          return True
        elif row == 1 and col == 1 and self.board[10] == ' ':
          return True
        elif row == 1 and col == 2 and self.board[11] == ' ':
          return True
        elif row == 2 and col == 0 and self.board[13] == ' ':
          return True
        elif row == 2 and col == 1 and self.board[14] == ' ':
          return True
        elif row == 2 and col == 2 and self.board[15] == ' ':
          return True
        else:
          return False
```

Answer (score 1):

The index in `self.board` depends on `row` and `col` in a simple way; so you just need to compute the right index to check, and then check whether there is a space character there. Assuming `row` and `col` are always both 0, 1, or 2, then that's all you need to check, so you can simply write:

```py
return self.board[5 + col + 4*row] == ' '
```

If you do need to check that `row` and `col` are within range, you can do a [subset](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset) test:

```py
return {row, col} <= {0, 1, 2} and self.board[5 + col + 4*row] == ' '
```

Note that if you're returning a Boolean, then you don't need to write and `if` statement to decide whether to `return True` or `return False`; you can just return the result of the Boolean condition directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```py
l = [
        [5, 6, 7],
        [9, 10, 11],
        [13, 14, 15]
        ]
if row in (0, 1, 2) and col in (0, 1, 2) and self.board[l[row][col]] == ' ':
    return True
return False
```

Comment: How about this?

Comment: Something like this?